# How to checksum for a DVD under Panther?

Tags: disk-utility, panther

I'm helping a friend checking if a DVD was burned properly but he's saying that  under Panther there's no *Images* menu in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Panther's `hdiutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.3/man1/hdiutil.1.html) supports checksumming, even if the Disk Utility GUI might not:

```
hdiutil checksum myimage.dmg -type MD5
```

(The supported types of checksums are listed in the man page. A common one seems to be `UDIF-CRC32`. If you use `UDIF-CRC32` or `UDIF-MD5` the checksums will be calculated separately per partition.)

Or you could always simply use the `md5` command:

```
md5 myimage.dmg
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [hdiutil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.3/man1/hdiutil.1.html) on the mounted drive:

```
hdiutil checksum /dev/disk1 -type UDIF-CRC32
```

The final calculated CRC appears at the bottom when the command completes running:

```
macbook:~ me$ hdiutil checksum /dev/disk1 -type UDIF-CRC32
Checksumming Driver Descriptor Map (DDM : 0)…
 Driver Descriptor Map (DDM : 0): calculated CRC32 $4F7D78B1
Checksumming Apple (Apple_partition_map : 1)
 Apple (Apple_partition_map : 1): calculated CRC32 $C4E22BED
Checksumming disk image (Apple_HFS : 2)
      disk image (Apple_HFS : 2): calculated CRC32 $04805620
Checksumming  (Apple_Free : 3)…
(Apple_Free : 3): calculated CRC32 $00000000
calculated CRC32 $52BB898F
```

This final calculated CRC (`$52BB898F` in the above example) is exactly the same as the one reported by Disk Utility:

[image: Disk Utility CRC]

You can use the [`diskutil list`](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/01/list-all-mounted-drives-and-their-partitions-from-the-terminal/) command for assistance in finding out the mounted drive's name.